# mvc3 razor index page with two partial pages with diff. page model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, razor

my index looks like this with page model which accepts list of objects

```
@model List<MyProject.Domain.Object>

@Html.Partial("PickDatePartial") 
@Html.Partial("ObjectPartial", Model)
```

My problem is within this first partial page, cause this partial page accept not list but single `@model MyProject.Domain.Object`

How can I achive this, in this current situation index page cannot be rendered cause it expect to receive list of objects.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one quick and dirty thing you could to is pass the first object to `PickDatePartial`

```
@Html.Partial("PickDatePartial", Model.First())
```

This is however not very clean. I would recommend creating a view model with two properties, 1) the whole list, 2) the one to be bound by `PickDatePartial`:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<MyProject.Domain.Object> MyList { get; set; }
    public MyProject.Domain.Object ObjectToBind { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `Index` action on your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myList = // instantiate list here
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel
    {
        MyList = myList,
        ObjectToBind = myList.First() // or whichever you need out of that list
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

You'll need to change the type of the model on the `Index` view, of course. Now the `Index` view looks like this:

```
@model IndexViewModel

@Html.Partial("PickDatePartial", Model.ObjectToBind) 
@Html.Partial("ObjectPartial", Model.MyList)
```

Comment: Another option is to change the ObjectToBind to an int selection index and pass @Html.Partial("PickDatePartial", Model.List[Model.Selection])

Answer (score 1):

If "PickDatePartial" expects one object, and you give it a list of objects, what object should it use?

It is up to you to decide what to do.

You could tell it to use the first object:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0) {
   @Html.Partial("PickDatePartial", Model[0])
}
```

or, you could call it for every object:

```
@foreach(var item in Model) {
   @Html.Partial("PickDatePartial", item)

}
```

The possibilities are endless.

Comment: thanks for your answer but that is not exactly what I need. Maybe my question was wrong :)
Here is concrete scenario
I have index page which accepts list of objects as model.
On same page I have two partial files, one for display pickdate on top of the index page (one instance) and second partial for rendering list of objects based on selected date.

So, second partial is fine it receive list of objects as it required  in page model declaration but in pick date partial I must use one instance of object to bind field on date model.

Comment: To complete
Index file
@model List<MyProject.Domain.Object>
..
@Html.Partial("PickDatePartial", ??) 
@Html.Partial("ObjectPartial", Model)
---
PickDatePartial file
@model MyProject.Domain.Object
...
.Bind(Model.SelectedDate).GetHtml()